# M2: Wrong totals, if I change item customPrice after quote->collectTotals()

Tags: magento2, checkout, quote, quoteitem, custom-prices

For example. There is 1 product in the cart with base price 35.
Working code:

```
foreach ($this->cart->getQuote()->getAllVisibleItems() as $item) {
    $item->setCustomPrice(11.11)
        ->setOriginalCustomPrice(11.11)
        ->getProduct()->setIsSuperMode(true);
}
// product rowTotal: 11.11
// cart subtotal/grandtotal: 11.11
```

NOT working code:

```
$this->cart->getQuote()->collectTotals(); // Attention to this line
foreach ($this->cart->getQuote()->getAllVisibleItems() as $item) {
    $item->setCustomPrice(11.11)
        ->setOriginalCustomPrice(11.11)
        ->getProduct()->setIsSuperMode(true);
}
// product rowTotal: 35.00
// product displayed price (customPrice): 11.11
// cart subtotal/grandtotal: 35.00
```

what I was trying to do:

```
$this->cart->getQuote()->collectTotals();
foreach ($this->cart->getQuote()->getAllVisibleItems() as $item) {
    $item->setCustomPrice(11.11)
        ->setOriginalCustomPrice(11.11)
        ->getProduct()->setIsSuperMode(true);
    $item->calcRowTotal();
}
 $this->cart->getQuote()->setTotalsCollectedFlag(false);
/** @var \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address $address */
foreach ($this->cart->getQuote()->getAllAddresses() as $address) {
    $address->setCollectShippingRates(true);
}
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't work.

Also it fixes if I reload cart page, but how to do it correctly without reload? What things should I re-set like `$quote->setTotalsCollectedFlag(false)` and `$address->setCollectShippingRates(true)`

And there is a question: What am I doing wrong? :)

**UPDATE:**

Magento version 2.2.2

It happens if quote already exists in the database (even if we have an empty cart). If I clear cookies / delete quotes from quote table, first product add doesn't proceed the trouble.

Comment: in which file or observer you are using to make this changes?

Comment: @AbhishekPanchal, I was trying Observer to cart_product_add_after event and plugin of method addProduct() in the Cart class

Comment: How many types of products you have ? Just simple??

Comment: Yes. At this moment just simple. I know, if a product has a parent, I need to set customPrice to the parent product.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've dig into the core and found a lot of unclear things, so I made this helpful but very dirty hack:

```
public function updateItemCustomPrice($item, $price)
{
    $item->setCustomPrice($price)
        ->setOriginalCustomPrice($price)
        ->setBaseTaxCalculationPrice($price)
        ->setTaxCalculationPrice($price)
        ->getProduct()->setIsSuperMode(true);
    $item->calcRowTotal();
}
```

Now I use this code instead of

```
$item->setCustomPrice(11.11)
    ->setOriginalCustomPrice(11.11)
    ->getProduct()->setIsSuperMode(true);
$item->calcRowTotal();
```

I'm still not sure of the correctness of this solution, so I invite you in the comments.